# Android initiate custom view with AttributeSet programmatically

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Hi I have create simple custom view called `Group`:

```
public class Group extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView headerTextView;

    public Group(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.Group, 0, 0);
        String string = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.Group_headerText);
        typedArray.recycle();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_group, this, true);

        headerTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        headerTextView.setText(string);

    }


}
```

and I want to create it dynamically in activity. I want to set my custom attribute attribute.
I found some solution with inflating but I really don't want to use that; it's not proper way to create object.
I need an example on how this area

```
Group g = new Group(v.getContext(),arrt);
```

just didn't know how to set arrt object and set my custom attribute in it

Comment: You can add a constructor that has only Context as parameter, and then call different view's setters

Answer (score 0):

Well, this constructor is normally used when you're inflating the view from XML. If you need to create dynamically your custom view, then provide a new constructor with no attribute set, only a `Context` and inflate there the XML:

```
public Group(Context context) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_group, this, true);

    headerTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
}
```

You'll need also a separate public method to provide the header text:

```
public void setHeader(String header) {
    headerTextView.setText(header);
}
```

That will be called from whoever created this class dynamically.

`I found some solution with inflating but I really don't want to use that; it's not proper way to create object.` I don't actually agree, because this way you're separating `View` from `Model` which is a foundation design pattern in programming.